# Xcode 6 No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found

Tags: ios, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I got p12 file from my colleague and installed into my mac and I find the certificate along with private key properly installed in my keychain.And also I installed provisioning profile.

I selected provisioning profile & respective certificate in XCODE 6 , when I try to build the app I get this error .

> ```
> "No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found."
> ```

**In the keychaing app:**
[image]

**In xcode 6:**

[image]

I tried the following but no luck.

- Re-start xcode.
- delete and re-installed p12 & provisioning profile.
- Turned-off 'Online Certificate status protol' & 'Certificate Revocation List' in keychain preference.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

**Note** : I do not have access to developer portal.

Comment: Is that provisioning profile created from same account ? Check the signing identity once again

Comment: @MidhunMP, I just exported the certificate as p12 from working machine and installed in my machine and used the same provisioning used in working machine,but it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Please set your code signing once again.

[image]

Comment: Then how the certificate will be selected ?

Comment: Set your bundle id properly which is links your certificated device with your xcode builting.....

Comment: This doesn't helped me.

Comment: @Sarat_Patel - Its not a answer.It is merely a comment

Answer (score 1):

Go to Open Xcode -> Product -> Edit Scheme -> Check wheter you selected Distribution for "Run" and "Profile"

If not change to Distribution,Because you are using distribution certificates.

Comment: I have 'Release' in my build configuration , I didn't understand about the configuration , can u pls elaborate ?

Comment: Sure....While you created Certificates in developer account...Which option you chosen for this project..Is it Development or Distribution???

Comment: Appstore Distribution.

Comment: If you chosen Development in Developer account while creating certificate for the particular App Id..you should select in build configuration as "Release" ....If you chosen Distribution,You have to select Distribution While you are running in an device(Note : That device UDID should be added in that certificate)

Comment: Then Change the Release to Distribution in Build Configuration...as i mentioned in answer

Answer (score 1):

Check with your colleague whether Provisioning Profile given to you is associated with that p12 certificate only or not .
You can goto your account portal (apple) -> Provisioning Profiles ->Development or Distribution -> Select your profile -> Edit -> Check Certificates (check Certificate date stored in your KeyChain & on portal selected certificate date ). If their is any mismatch then someone has revoked your p12 certificate , you need to get new p12 & generate new provisioning profile .

You have your apple account credentials then i can assist you for the same.

Comment: I do not have access to the apple account and that is the issue . BTW I have published apps in appstore and I know the above mentioned one .

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that not only your target is using the correct provisioning but also in the project section.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This has to be a comment not an answer.With you points I know you can't comment.But you've to earn the points and comment !

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 creates the provisioning profiles by itself. You can detect them using "XC" as the prefix for the provisioning profile name. You can use that provisioning profile.

If this doesn't work, then cross check the bundle identifier of your Xcode project and the one in the provisioning profile.

To see the bundle identifier of the provisioning profile, you can use iPhone Configuration Utility software on your Mac.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I donot have access to developer account.